# Loading DataGridView from another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have been a long time reader of questions and answers on this site and this is my first question.

I have a Datagridview I want to load from a MySQL database.  I can get the code to work if the datagridview is contained in the form I am writing the code in.  If I request try and load it onto another form it does not work

The top bit of code works and the latter bit does not.

```vb
Public Sub LoadGrid3()
    Dim job As String = TextBox10.Text
        MySql.AddParam("@job", job)
    Try
        MySql.ExecQuery("select * from imprint.jobs_commonfields where jobno = @job")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    If MySql.RecordCount > 0 Then DataGridView1.DataSource = MySql.mysqlds.Tables(0)
End Sub



Public Sub LoadGrid3()
    Dim job As String = TextBox10.Text
    MySql.AddParam("@job", job)
    Try
        MySql.ExecQuery("select * from imprint.jobs_commonfields where jobno = @job")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    If MySql.RecordCount > 0 Then Form3.job_detail.DataSource = MySql.mysqlds.Tables(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work means any errors?  What is that MySql object?  Form3 doesn't look like a proper reference to an existing Form3 instance.

Comment: Why have one form get involved in another's business?  Pass the "jobNo" to the other form and let it create its own DataSource.  Note that using default form instances will likely bite you eventually.

Comment: Also, please read [Ask] and take the [Tour] so you are familiar with things now that you are participating.